# Paste String Data from UIPastboard

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, avfoundation

I made an IOS app that using OCR to scan barcodes and copies the data to UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "barcodeId") as! String from a receipt. I'm trying to auto-populate the data taken from I've managed to pass the data to the element ID, But the data scanned using OCR doesn't populate the correct value. Below information from the console. NOTE: I've obscured the URL, Since It's a private URL. Optional(8.906010283900207e+17) is what I need to pass to the element ID on the webbased form.

Thanks!

Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('ERECEIPT').value = 0890601028390020718'), WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=36, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=https://google.com, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}
Optional(8.906010283900207e+17)

thanks!

Comment: Have you static web-based form which added in bundle ? or dynamic form url ?

Comment: No, I did not, I'm a fairly new dev. So can you please drill in how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Note that if you are using Swift 4 (Xcode 9.x) your method signature is wrong. `func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {`

Comment: Thanks, @LeoDabus Can you give me an example on how to auto-populate the scanned value on the form?

Comment: @Tiktak132 Sorry man but I have no idea what you mean by "auto-populate the scanned value on the form" considering that you are not showing any code related to your web-based form.

Comment: @LeoDabus I've added it sorry for not clarifying. I've removed the url since it's work related.

Comment: Why do you need to add the string to your clipboard if your goal is to add it to the webform?

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm building the app for a retail store. The want to ideally scan the receipt. When the web form loads the string needs to populate in the barcode section of the form. I know they can easily paste it. But they want it to auto-populate.

Comment: @LeoDabus If you have a better method, Please let me know!

Comment: You have issue with your instance. You need to write savedBarcodeData.string. also you need to check it is not nil.

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you show me how to do this programmatically? I have verified it is not nill

Answer (score 1):

when you barcode scan completed then there are mainly two data arrived one is type of barcode and second one is data that you scanned. Make sure when you are going to paste it it is valid string data, then write following code to copy that barcode data

`UIPasteboard.general.string = barcodeData`.

Then on the pasting of this data, write following code:

`if let barcodeData = UIPasteboard.general.string { your code here }`

Comment: Thanks Paul! What code would I put in between the curly brackets?

Comment: This code you need to write in webViewDidFinishLoad method. Inside this curly braces replace barcode data in you html form.

Comment: Thanks @Mahipal Singh for edit answer and formatting code.

Comment: My form is URL request, how would I format this in a way to populate on a certain field on the form? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Yes man, There should be one field in your html form to replace this value. i.e. #barcodedat#, So, first get html string from url and replace your barcode data, then load your html string inside webview. This is working for static HTML form. But if your form has navigation then need to replace by getting id of elements.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to do it programmatically? Thanks so much for your help so far man!